# How to load amsfonts/umsa.fd

Tags: math-mode, catcodes, amsfonts

I changed the catcode of `F` to active in my environment and now I can't use math mode. The problem is this:

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd
! Undefined control sequence.
l.29 \Provides
              File{umsa.fd}    [2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A]
```

I solved it by using `\phantom{$a$}` before changing catcodes but I don't know what is the correct approach? I tried `\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath}` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change catcodes you should expect things to break, but in this case it's probably easily fixable the fd file is only input once so just make sure that you have some math before you change the catcode (you can discard it, so `\sbox0{$x$}` with an unused box ) or simply `\input` the fd file.

Alternatively (and probably safer) if your environment is math (you give no clues) do not make F active, instead give it an active definition, but leave it catcode11 but give it `\mathcode"8000` so the active definition is used in math mode without affecting text mode or use in command names such as `\ProvidesFile`.